# Why Tor is not already a decentralized network?

Tags: censorship

I'm wondering since a long time why the developers of Tor do not have already make Tor a truly P2P network where the **entire** Tor network would be 100% decentralized, only running be voluntary and where nobody could take the network down or interfere with it, even versus a big adversary (eg : the United States)

One example of one attack that I remember because of the fact that tor is not a fully-decentralized net : https://blog.torproject.org/blog/possible-upcoming-attempts-disable-tor-network

Is this at least considered in one future version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer would be simple: Decentralization is a difficult problem.

I suggest you read [The fifteen year struggle of decentralizing
privacy-enhancing technology](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.4818.pdf). In this paper the authors list 4 major problems that needs to be addressed for decentralization:

1. Incentives in decentralized systems

Most people take up bandwidth more than they donate and proposals to introduce incentives into Tor have failed. . If one would also have to build an incentive system into a decentralized system, there should be a way to manage the ratings of each client without allowing falsification.

2. NAT traversal

A truly decentralized system requires the participating nodes to have direct connection to each other. But because IPv4 addresses are getting scarce, ISP often tend to put more subscribers in a single network address suing carrier-grade NAT.

3. Bootstrapping new nodes

If in a decentralized system one client wants to become a bridge or relay, there is no central directory server to tell a new node where to locate neighbours.

4. Key exchange

With a decentralized model, for a secure communication users will have to share the keys directly with each other making it vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attack.

They also give a comparison of decentralized peer-to-peer overlay networks:

[image]

It is interesting to read their conclusion:

> ..we conclude that there is no fully decentralized system capable of
>   offering Tor anonymity today. For the first time we document in
>   detail, the amount of wasted effort and pain spent in
>   decentralization. The current generation of technology lead by Tor
>   still has room for improvement, while the next generation is only just
>   appearing on the horizon. The major problems involving
>   decentralization are excruciatingly difficult to overcome. None of the
>   projects have succeeded in making the internet secure and private.

Answer (score 0):

Now though: decentralised networks are here, built on blockchain.
zeronet.io is one example and web3 will have a blockchain backbone. As a side note, stor.j provides a 100% trust-less, encrypted decentralised blockchain powered ‘super cloud’ storage solution that smashed Dropbox into 10000000 pieces of junk.